# how can i define dtypes when using io.parsers.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

When I load my data by using the io.parser.read_csv with following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names_header = ['date', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', ' f', 'g', 'h ]  

df_csv_data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(station_path, skiprows=5, parse_dates= True, index_col=0, na_values=[-999], names= names_header , sep=';', header=None , squeeze=True)
```

I got this dtypes:
BUT a should also be a float64 - how can i convert it?

```
>>> df_csv_data.dtypes
a     object
b     float64
c     float64
d     float64
e     float64
f     float64
g     float64
h     float64
dtype: object
```

when I'm using a dict to define it, like this:

```
dtype={'a': np.float64}
```

I got this error message:

```
ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of <f4 for object dtyped data in column 1
```

has anyone an idea to solve it?

Comment: Can you show what 'a' actually is, also can you post raw data to reproduce your problem

Comment: how can i post my data?

Comment: As a raw input, we only need enough to reproduce your error, it's likely that you have malformed data, otherwise some url to somewhere we can download it

Comment: 2011-02-09 08:51:00;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999

2011-02-09 08:52:00;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999

2011-02-09 08:53:00;335.79;738.00;81.00;238.00;341.00;1.00;1.00;1.00;1.00

2011-02-09 08:54:00;335.55;734.00;81.00;238.00;340.00;1.00;1.00;1.00;1.00

2011-02-09 08:55:00;327.29;707.00;81.00;238.00;332.00;1.00;1.00;1.00;1.00

2011-02-09 08:56:00;317.23;678.00;80.00;238.00;322.00;1.00;1.00;1.00;1.00

Comment: 2011-02-09 08:51:00;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999

2011-02-09 08:52:00;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999;-999

2011-02-09 08:53:00;335.79;738.00;81.00;238.00;341.00;1.00;1.00;1.00;1.00

2011-02-09 08:54:00;335.55;734.00;81.00;238.00;340.00;1.00;1.00;1.00;1.00

2011-02-09 08:55:00;327.29;707.00;81.00;238.00;332.00;1.00;1.00;1.00;1.00

2011-02-09 08:56:00;317.23;678.00;80.00;238.00;322.00;1.00;1.00;1.00;1.00

Comment: Unclear how this data relates to your question but your first column is a datet time string, are you expecting this to be convertible to a float?

Comment: no, the first column is the date index - see here:
df_csv_data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(station_path, skiprows=5, parse_dates= True, index_col=0, na_values=[-999], names= names_header , sep=';', header=None , squeeze=True)

i've problems with the secound column

Comment: Using your code I get the first 2 rows containing `NaN` values as you've specified that -999 is `NaN` but the dtypes are all float so I can't reproduce your error

Comment: @steff did you ever resolve this?

Comment: thanks you for asking!
the problem was a wrong format in the input data.